# Returning JSON and XML using the same entity class

Tags: java

I have this controller code that is returning XML , how can i make it return JSON with minimum line of code or just with few annotation on the entity class or the controller .

```
        @GetMapping(value = "/check", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
            @ResponseBody
            public ResponseEntity<Result> getWapiResult(@RequestParam String sn){
                return new ResponseEntity(
                        wapiService.getWapiData(sn).getBody(),
                        new HttpHeaders(),
                        HttpStatus.OK);
            }
```

This is the entity class

```
        @XmlRootElement
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        public class Result {
        
            private boolean complete;
            private int srcsize;
        
            private String urlpath;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change what controller produces

```
@GetMapping(value = "/check", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Result> getWapiResult(@RequestParam String sn){
            return new ResponseEntity(
                    wapiService.getWapiData(sn).getBody(),
                    new HttpHeaders(),
                    HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

And remove unnecessary annotations from Entity

```
    public class Result {
        private boolean complete;
        private int srcsize;
        private String urlpath;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your application is in Spring.
On Controller:  The @ResponseBody annotation tells the controller that the object returned is automatically serialized into JSON and passed back into the HttpResponse object.
So, keep annotation only @ResponseBody. In @Get Mapping, keep only value.
@GetMapping(value = "/check").
On Entity class: Remove all annotation of @XML. Keep a no-arg constructor in Result class.
This will return JSON as ResponseBody.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i need the XML part also .

Comment: API will return one format that you want. In case you want to have both the format i.e. XML and JSON in your case, of the response body, you may create two APIs, one returning JSON, the other XML.